# Proving that $\mu(\cap_{k=1}^nE_k) > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

**Problem:** Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mu)$ and $E_1,\dots, E_n \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(E_k) > n-1$. Prove that $\mu(\cap_{k=1}^n E_k) > 0$.

Here's my attempt.

> *Proof:* Because $\mu$ is a probability measure we know that for any $E \in \mathcal{F}$ we have that $\mu(E)+\mu(E^c) = 1$. Note that in particular because $E_1,\dots,E_n \in \mathcal{F}$ their finite intersection is also an element of the sigma algebra. Then it follows that
> $$
> \mu \left( \bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k \right)+ \mu \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nE_k^c \right) = 1,
> $$
> and so $\mu(\cap_{k=1}^n E_k) = 1-\mu(\cup_{k=1}^n E_k^c)$. But then it follows that
> \begin{align}
> \mu \left( \bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k \right) &= 1 -\mu \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nE_k^c \right) \\
> & \geq 1- \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(E_k^c) \\
> & = 1 - \sum_{k=1}^n (1-\mu(E_k)) \\
> & = 1-n + \sum_{l=1}^n \mu(E_k) \\
> & > (1-n)+(n-1) \\
> & > 0,
> \end{align}
> proving the claim. Here line (2) follows from the subadditivy of the measure, line (3) is because $\mu$ is a probability measure, and line (5) follows from our assumptions about the $E_n$.

Does everything here seem alright, are there any mistakes I'm mising? I'm not sure if there's a faster way to do this, other students I know have said it's only a few lines but I don't see the approach. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks correct to me.